# Please explain how an SSO works using encrypted hash

Tags: authentication, hash, single-sign-on

I'm reading up on how to implement single sign on between two sites and came across this example http://dev.assistly.com/docs/portal/multipass.  Basically one site passes an encrypted JSON hash containing user id, login expiration and some other customer info.  The hash is created using a site key as password and api key as the salt.

As I understand it, hashing algorithms work one way.  For example, site #2 could hash the same values and compare the result against the hash passed by site #1 to determine if it is authentic & valid.  However, site #2 can't reverse the hashed value passed by site #1 to determine what values were used.

Here's my question.  In the SSO example I linked to and described above, all of the information is presumably shared between the two sites in advance of the sign-on.  For example, both sites presumably know the user id, password, salt, etc.  However, I assume that the expiration  datetime value is different for each login occurrence.  If the expiration datetime changes with each login and if it is not something that can be shared beforehand between the two sites, wouldn't it be impossible for site #2 to validate the hash it receives from site #1?

I must be missing something in my understanding of how this works.  Or perhaps I'm making faulty assumptions.  Please explain.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assistly's terminology is a bit confusing. When they talk about hashes they are actually referring to JSON hashes which are just maps of values ... not cryptographic hashes. You'll see they also refer to AES encryption which is two-way so you would encrypt the data and they would decrypt it.